Order of Orbit and Stabilizer of $e_1 \in \mathbb F_p^n $ in $GL_n (\mathbb F_p)$ Group
Suppose $\mathbb F_p$ is the finite field with a prime number $p$ of elements. The general linear group $GL_n (\mathbb F_p)$ is the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_p$ under matrix multiplication. The elements of this group with matrix multiplication act on $\mathbb F_p^n$:
$\phi : GL_n (\mathbb F_p) \times \mathbb F_p^n \rightarrow \mathbb F_p^n$ and
$\phi(g, v) = gv$ for all $g\in GL_n (\mathbb F_p)$ and $v\in \mathbb F_p^n$.
The Orbit of $e_1=(1,0,...,0)\in\mathbb F_p^n$ is
$$Orb(e_1) = \{\phi(g, e_1)=ge_1\ | g\in GL_n (\mathbb F_p)\}$$
and
$$Stab(e_1) = \{\ g\in GL_n (\mathbb F_p)|\phi(g, e_1)=e_1\}=\{\ g\in GL_n (\mathbb F_p)|ge_1=e_1\}.$$
I want to find the order of $Orb(e_1)$ and $Stab(e_1)$.

I know $|Orb(e_1)|$ is equal to the number of different first columns of $GL_n (\mathbb F_p)$ matrices but I don't know how to count them.
I know $|Stab(e_1)|$ is equal to the number of matrices with $e_1^T$ as their first column but I don't know how to count them.


From basic linear algebra, given any two nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$ in a vector space $V$, there is an invertible linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$ such that $T(v)=w$. That is, the action is transitive on nonzero vectors. Once you know that, the rest follows, using the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

@ArturoMagidin thank you but I cant use this theorem for this problem.

It is still the case that every nonzero vector lies in the orbit. So  part 1 is trivial. Part 2 is also trivial, since it amounts to counting the number of elements of $\mathsf{GL}_{n-1}(\mathbb{F}_p)$, which will be the distinct minors of the $(1,1)$ entry of your matrix. And, by the way, youl would save everyone, including yourself, time and effort if you provided appropriate context. If you cannot use a basic, standard result about orbits and stabilizers, then you need to say so up front and clearly, lest you just waste everyone's  time.
